# Output of data.table aggregation as list

Tags: r, list, data.table

How can I group a `data.table` e.g. with filenames by metadata and store each group in a `list`-item?

**Input:**

```
DT <- data.table(files = 1:10, meta = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2,4)))
```

I thought of something like:

```
MyList <- DT[, files, by = meta] #something like that
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 7 8 9 10
```

The above example is simplified in the case that meta are actually more columns (to group by) and some rows are selected before.
Is there a simple way to go (preferable a `data.table`-solution), or do I have to use some other way like

```
lapply(unique(DT$meta), function(x) DT[meta == x]$files)
```

?

Comment: Why do you believe you need this output?

Comment: To read each file in each list-item and process it separatly in many further steps. I'm aware of the possibility to process files within data.table with something like ``DT[, sapply(files, read.csv), by = meta]`` or similar, but that would be not very useful if there are many steps instead of ``read.csv``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap it in a `list`

```
DT1 <- DT[, .(files = list(files)), meta]
DT1$files
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1]  7  8  9 10
```